# Smallest element §a§ such that Jacobisymbol $(a, n) = -1$.

Tags: quadratic-residues

I want to get an upper bound for the smallest $a$ and a natural number $n$ such that the Jacobisymbol is
$$
\big(\frac{a}{n}\big) = -1.
$$

I know the following:
Let $p>3$ be prime and let $a_p$ be the smallest quadratic non-residue mod $p$.
Then
$$
a_p \leq
   \begin{cases}
      0{,}9\cdot p^{\frac{1}{4}}\cdot \ln(p), \text{ for } n\equiv 1 \pmod 4, \\
      1{,}1\cdot p^{\frac{1}{4}}\cdot \ln(p), \text{ for } n\equiv 3 \pmod 4.
   \end{cases}
$$

Furthermore, I know that for a number $n$ there exists an $a$ such that
$
\big(\frac{a}{n}\big) = -1
$
if and only if $n$ is not a perfect square.

I suppose that this is the same for composite $n$.
My thoughts for the proof (here only for $\equiv 1\pmod 4$).
Let $n$ be a natural number with $n\equiv 1\pmod 4$.
Furthermore let $a_p$ be the smallest element such that the Jacobisymbol
$$
\big(\frac{a_p}{n}\big) = -1.
$$
If $n$ is prime, we get $a_p \leq 0{,}9\cdot n^{\frac{1}{4}}\cdot \ln(n)$ right away.

Now let $n$ be composite with its prime decomposition
$
n = \prod\limits_{p\in\mathbb P} p^{\alpha_p}.
$
To clearify a point an advance: It is possible that this number has prime divisors $p\equiv 3\pmod 4$.
That's why I will use the formula with $1,{1}\cdot\dots$ once.

Then we get for the Jacobisymbol
$$
-1 
= \big(\frac{a_p}{n}\big)
= \prod\limits_{p\in\mathbb P}\big(\frac{a_p}{p}\big)^{\alpha_p}.
$$

Here I am stuck.
I could have a look at the greatest prime divisor $p_m$.
But it might be, that the smallest quadratic non-residue for this divisor is very small, whereas it is very big for smaller divisors.
So I cannot conclude that is smaller than
$
1{,}1\cdot p^{\frac{1}{4}}\cdot \ln(p)
$
for all $p$.

Comment: If you want $a$ to be a quadratic nonresidue modulo $n$, then it suffices for it to be a quadratic nonresidue modulo any prime dividing $n$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Ok, but I want to the Jacobisymbol to be $-1$. Consider $n = 11\cdot 13\cdot 23$. Then the number $2$ is a quadratic nonresidue mod n, and the legendre symbols $(2,11) = (2,13) = -1$ and $(2,23) = 1$. But the Jacobisymbol $(2,n) = 1$.

Comment: The title of your question says "smallest quadratic nonresidue", and the first sentence says "smallest quadratic nonresidue". I know you want the Jacobi symbol to be negative, but I don't know why. It seems to me to be much more significant that $2$ is a nonresidue modulo $15$, than that the Jacobi symbol is $+1$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson You are totally right, I am sorry. I edited my question.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A112046 is a tabulation of something close to what you want. Unfortunately, it says nothing about estimates.